# Duplicate symbol between ExactTarget and third party

Tags: ios

I have a similar problem to the issue mentioned in [this SE post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96590/exacttarget-library-duplicated-symbol-ios/97255#97255), with 197 duplicate symbols found.

The problem is that in my app sqlite3 is implemented by another third party product (IBM Worklight) through the sqlcipher framework.  When I removed the reference to the sqlcipher framework it generated 30 undefined symbol errors.

Update:
I noticed that the sqlcipher framework includes a sqlite3.h file, I tried commenting out the conflicting declarations, and even deleted the file, but it made no difference.

Is there another way around the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're aware of this issue and have addressed it for our next SDK release.

We've namespaced our sqlite usage so that it can play more fairly within an app.

This will be released later this month; please let us know how it works for you!

Brian M. Criscuolo, Senior Mobile Engineer